# .Net Core 2.0 xUnit project - What are these DLLs?

Tags: .net-core, xunit.net

I've created a dotnet core xunit project via the command line like this:

`dotnet new xunit`

When I open the solution in Visual Studio 2017, and click the 'Show All Files' button for the Test project, I see what looks like some DLLs in the project root but the DLLs aren't physically in that folder.

Can someone explain what these DLLs are and why it displays like they're in the root folder (when they're not really)?

It just looks wrong...

```
xunit.runner.reporters.netcoreapp10.dll
xunit.runner.utility.netcoreapp10.dll
xunit.runner.visualstudio.dotnetcore.testadapter.dll
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have the "Show All Files" option enabled so you also see hidden files.

Unit ships dlls used by the visual studio / `dotnet test` runners so that your tests work in visual studio and on the command line. they are normally hidden.